# Djang/websocket not sending messages

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, websocket, daphne

i'm using django and daphne and websocket to make a chat room by following a tutorial on youtube..everything worked fine , but when i send the message it does'nt show the message in the screen....it does not show any errors in the server side ..but shows 2 warniings and one error in the browser console

im intermediate in django but completely new to web sockets

Here's my script tag:

```
{% endblock %} {% block scripts %} {{ room.slug|json_script:"json-roomname" }}
{{ request.user.username|json_script:"json-username"}}
<script>
  const roomName = JSON.parse(
    document.getElementById("json-roomname").textContent
  );
  const usrName = JSON.parse(
    document.getElementById("json-username").textContent
  );

  const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    "ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/" + roomName + "/"
  );

  chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log("onemssage");
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    if (data.message) {
      let html = '<div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">';
      html += '<p class="font-semibold">' + data.username + "</p>";
      html += "<p>" + data.message + "</p></div>";

      document.querySelector("#chat-messages").innerHTML += html;
    } else {
      alert("The message was empty!");
    }
  };

  chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("onclose", e);
  };

  document
    .querySelector("#chat-message-submit")
    .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const messageInputDom = document.querySelector("#chat-message-input");
      const message = messageInputDom.value;

      chatSocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          message: message,
          username: usrName,
          room: roomName,
        })
      );

      messageInputDom.value = "";

      return false;
    });
</script>
```

here's my python file:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name



        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
    
    async def disconnect(self,close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name

        )
    
    async def recieve(self,text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']
        username = data['username']
        room = data['room']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'username':username,
                'room':room,
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self,event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        room = event['room']


        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username':username,
            'room':room,
        }))
```

here's routing.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns =[
    path('ws/<str:room_name>/',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

I want the message to be sent, when hitting the send button